# SQL Join a column with multiple lookups in one cell

Tags: sql

I have a Company lookup table where there are 7 different Companies. The lookupkey start with one and ends with seven.
The problem is that the fact table has a companykey which can look like this (1,2,3,4) which mean the row have 4 Companies. But how do I make a join when all the values are inside one cell?

```
The company Table look like this  
ID   Name  
1    Company1  
2    Company2  
3    Company3  
....
```

The Fact table looks like this:

```
Id Amount    Company  
1  100 Usd   (1,2,3)  
2  200 Usd   (1,2)  
....
```

The result

```
Id Amount    Company   
1  100 Usd   (Company1,Company2,Company3)  
2  200 Usd   (Company1,Company2)
```

I didn't design the database it's just the way it is
Thank you

Comment: Provide sample data and desired result to clarify

Comment: Please show the input data, what you want to get, *and* what you have tried. In the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *table have a companykey which can look like this (1,2,3,4)* - you should really redesign your table schema. Concatenation of multiple values into one is definitely bad idea, use separate relations table instead.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Split the string then compare. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1665/sql-server-clr-and-sql-split-functions-to-parse-a-delimited-string/

Answer (score 0):

You can either split that string `Fact.Company` into array and use array comparison operator, like for example in PostgreSQL it would be:

`JOIN Fact ON Company.ID = ANY(translate(Fact.Company, '()', '{}')::integer[])`

Other way is to split it into set of rows, not sure what is available in your RDBMS for such task.

Comment: I am using T-sql - are there a way to do it with that?